# Does Stone-Weierstrass apply in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory

Does the Stone-Weierstrass theorem (Weierstrass approximation theorem) apply in $\mathbb{R}$.

The Stone-Weierstrass theorem in $\mathbb{R}$ would be:

> Given continuous $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists a polynomial $p(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @NormalHuman That might just be it. I mean, why I'm asking it.

Comment: @NormalHuman: There is a locally compact version concerning the algebra of functions vanishing at infinity. Although, I doubt that this is what the OP was referring to.

Comment: I was given a hint that this has something to with the power series expansion of the exponential function.

Comment: Can you give a precise statement of the theorem you would want to be true?

Comment: Given continuous $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists a polynomial $p(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @mavavilj Counterexamples are easy.  Take any nonconstant bounded $f$.  Nonconstant polynomials are unbounded.

Comment: @RobertIsrael What's the counterexample for "there does not exist a polynomial"?

Comment: I mean, $f$ and $\epsilon$ such that there does not exist a polynomial ...

Comment: Oh yeah, so that's where the exponential function comes in.

Comment: Function $\sin(x)$ is continuous, but if $p$ is a continuous function with $|p(x) - \sin(x)|<1/2$ for all $x$ then $p$ has infinitely many zeros.  So $p$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: @GEdgar Why does $p$ have infinitely many zeros?